# Is there canon explanation on Cortana changing appearance?

Tags: halo

Master Chief can change his armour, but why Cortana is changing her appearance? Every game uses different model of Cortana. Rolland AI is not changing his appearance during Halo 4 and 5.

Comment: Well, she is manipulating hologram projectors to look however she wants (she changes size and color in game occasionally, especially in the Control Room of the first Halo). Cortana's appearance has always struck me as the least problematic of the franchise's art changes, unlike say, Brutes being redesigned every game or Miranda and Truth having new voices in Halo 3.

Comment: @Nolimon oh, maybe you forgot elites redesign in Halo 4 and 5? :)

Comment: Cortana is just a little circle on my home bar, no? XD

Comment: @Skooba is her appearance as circle in icon bar can be considered canon?